# Retrieve Session value in Javascript from Code behind file Aspx.cs

Tags: javascript, asp.net, session

I am storing some value in session through code behind file named Index4.aspx.cs by using this code:
     Session[txtUsername.Text.ToUpper() + "ChannelID_BC"] = 1111110;

But now how to retrieve it in Index$.aspx page through JavaScript

Answer (score 0):

Session is server side storage, so you can't access it from JavaScript. The closest you can get is to initiate an Ajax request from JavaScript that will invoke server side code that in turn will access session. However, it's not possible to access Session from JavaScript directly.

Answer (score 0):

Try this, this is used for get the session value through JavaScript, here We use ajax to call code behind method and return session value and at last alert it.

JS

```
$.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: 'Index4.aspx' + '/' + 'GetData',
        data: "{}",
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        dataType: "json",
        async: true,
        cache: false,
        success: function (response) {
            var content=response.d;
            alert(content);
        }
    });
```

CS

```
 [WebMethod]
        public static string GetData(string Text, string Col, int Status)
        {
            string DataOutput = "";
            DataOutput =Session[txtUsername.Text.ToUpper() + "ChannelID_BC"];
            return DataOutput;
        }
```

Comment: Gives error on CS page Object Reference is required for Non static field, property, method
Also in JS page i hav to get data from CS page so is it right to use POST

Comment: wrote an error function in ajax displaying an alert with watever the error, which is getting executed.
which displays [Object object]
?????

Comment: because it is static function and also use webmethod please use webmethod system class also